# how to efficiently parse a string in c

Tags: c, string, char

I have:

```
char *str = "abc def  abcdef ghi   xyz";
```

I want to assign

```
const char *a = "abc"; 
const char *b = "def";
const char *c = "abcdef";
const char *d = "ghi";
const char *e = "xyz";
```

Key here is that number of spaces can be more than one.

Please suggest an efficient way.

Comment: Are the number of output tokens always 5?

Comment: @Praetorian: It's not fixed. But I know that first 6 are what I am most interested in.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Corrected. For my education: why is it not a good idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hari - How are you going to declare a new pointer for every tokenized string at run time ? Instead you need to use array of pointers.

Comment: @Hari: String literals are read-only in C, or `const` in other words.  C only supports non-`const` pointers to string literals as an archaic throwback.  But you cannot modify string literals, so you should always use `const` to enforce that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Efficency is in the eye of the beholder.  But take a look at [`strtok`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/); however, you will need to work with a copy of the string that can be modified.

Note that `char *str = "blah"` is not a good idea.  You should be using `const char *str = "blah"`.

Comment: Regarding efficiency, I just want to make sure that if I do this operation thousands of times, I better use something which is not killing me right away. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some sample code using [`strok_r`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_strtok.htm). It is the re-entrant version of `strtok` (not sure whether it is part of the C standard). Also, I've assumed that you only have 5 tokens. If you want to have more you'll have to modify the code to allocate additional memory using `realloc`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char *str = "abc def  abcdef ghi   xyz";
  char *dup = strdup( str );
  char **output = malloc( 5 * sizeof(char *) );
  char *p = dup;
  char *nextp = NULL;
  int i = 0;

  if( dup == NULL ) {
    // handle error
  }

  for( i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    output[i] = strtok_r( p, " ", &nextp );
    p = NULL;
  }

  for( i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    printf( "output[%d] = %s\n", i, output[i] );
  }

  free( dup );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char *str = strdup("abc def  abcdef ghi   xyz");

        char *a = strtok(str, " ");
        char *b = strtok(NULL, " ");
        char *c = strtok(NULL, " ");
        char *d = strtok(NULL, " ");
        char *e = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("a=%s|b=%s|c=%s|d=%s|e=%s\n", a, b, c, d, e);
        free(str);
        return 0;
}
```

But I would call strtok from a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` treats multiple contiguous spaces as a single delimiter so it should resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

For space delimited data, you can actually use `sscanf` with appropriate magic in the format string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
    char *str = "abc def  abcdef ghi   xyz";

    // The simple example
    char *a, *b, *c, *d, *e;
    sscanf(str," %a[^ ] %a[^ ] %a[^ ] %a[^ ] %a[^ ]", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);

    // Dynamically constructing the format string and a char*[] of strings
    enum { NVAR = 5 };
    char **list;
    char *fmtx = " %a[^ ]";
    char *fmt;
    int i;
    list = malloc(NVAR*sizeof*list);
    for (i=0; i < NVAR; i++) list[i] = malloc(sizeof**list);
    fmt = malloc(NVAR*strlen(fmtx)+1);
    fmt[0] = '\0';
    for (i=0; i < NVAR; i++) strcat(fmt,fmtx);
    sscanf(str,fmt,list,list+1,list+2,list+3,list+4,list+5);
    for (i=0; i < NVAR; i++) if (list[i]) puts(list[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize when posting that the 'a' option in a string format specifier is a GNU extension. So this is not "portable C".